# How can I disable the front status LED when charging my device?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, charging, notification-led

Charging my smartphone the front LED is always shining annoyingly green. This bothers me especially while reading an ebook which is why I am looking for a way to disable this feature.

So how do I disable the front status LED?

My smartphone is a Huawei Honor U8860, but I'm hoping to find a device-agnostic solution, be it in form of a hidden setting or app that adds the option to disable the front status LED.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seem any such options or settings for any device so far. You can try these apps

1. [LightFlow Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite)
2. [Adjbrightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deskangel.adjbrightness)

but I doubt these would work properly. (I can't check as my device doesn't have LED notification light.)

I believe this kind of things are only doable via Custom ROMs. You would have to check your device development forums. Start here - [Huwaei U8860 - xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1552038).

I don't think you can get an universal solution. If there has been a way to do it via Android APIs it would already be in Settings I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that an App could get the low-level access needed to turn of the LED while charging. Your best bet is a custom ROM that has this low-level access and provides an API for an App or user setting. I would look at cyanogen mod.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an app which works nicely without root for the Sony Z1 Compact:
[Disable Charging LED](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.deck36.fyled)

Maybe this is worth a try for you, too.